# The Firebase implementation within an AAR I'm using causes my App to crash

Tags: android, firebase, android-multidex

I had been contacted to put a new library in the form of an AAR into my application. It worked fine before adding this AAR, but after that, every time I start it up, it crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
09-10 21:10:55.272 10354-10354/? W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource;
    at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(Unknown Source)
    at com.picmix.mobile.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:89)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.picmix.mobile-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.picmix.mobile-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    ... 16 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

From my experience, this kind of error is because I hadn't enabled MultiDex support. The strange thing is that I have it enabled, my gradle file contains the following line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

The application I use in the manifest extends `MultiDexApplication` instead of just `Application`.

So is it something with that AAR?

Comment: You should be using `implementation` instead of `compile`, but did you implement Firebase RemoteConfig in your own project? I think you need to do that. Also, to enable multi-dex, you need to add `multiDexEnabled true` under the `defaultConfig` block.

Comment: It's already there, and unfortunately the source code uses the v2.2.3 Gradle Plugin, and I don't know how to implement Product Flavors yet. BTW, does implementing the Firebase RemoteConfig require another dependency?

Comment: it needs firebase-core

Comment: @TheWanderer I've updated my gradle plugin to v3.1.4, and realized that the logs also said something like `can not find class <firebase>.Tasks`, and then found out I had the dependency `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:$gmsVersion"`. That might've caused the conflict that removed the Firebase's Task/Tasks/related classes from the APK. I commented it out and now the APK doesn't crash on startup. Though I'm not sure about the definite cause.